# Android: using framework drawables in custom button selector

Tags: android

I'd need to create custom button, but I'd want to use framework's default button highlight colors for pressed and focused states. My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686430/android-use-default-highlight-colors-in-a-custom-button).

My selector code looks like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/grid_selector_background_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/grid_selector_background_focus"/>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#EAEAEA"/>
            <stroke
                    android:width="0dp"
                    android:color="#A0A0A0"/>
            <corners
                    android:radius="0dp"/>
            <padding
                    android:left="10dp"
                    android:top="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp"
                    android:bottom="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

So I'm basically trying to reference drawables **grid_selector_background_pressed** and **grid_selector_background_focus**. The dev environment does find those drawables as it auto-suggests them upon typing, but then gives "Resource is not public" when compiling.

Is there a way to use the above mentioned framework drawables?

Pom

Answer (score 0):

You can go into your android-sdk folder, pick your platform, and copy the drawables from the appropriate res/drawable folder into your local drawable folder, and reference them from there.