# Removing Android ToggleButton's green indicator light

Tags: android, togglebutton

I would like my app to have a day of week selector with multiple day selection capability. I'm using ToggleButtons for this right now, but because of the indicator lights a ToggleButton takes too much space on the screen. Without the lights, my ToggleButtons would look like normal (toggleable) Buttons and they could fit in one row. How can I hide the lights?

Answer (score 14):

The answer is this part:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
```

For example, following will make the light disappear and toggle button would look like a default button, but with the toggle functionality:

```
    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/your_btn"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textOn="On" android:textOff="Off"
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default" />
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer is only the android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default" part though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `android:background` drawable for them, that will override the graphics including the indicator light. If you look at [Android: using framework drawables in custom button selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668454/android-using-framework-drawables-in-custom-button-selector), there's instructions for copying resources from the SDK to your own project. You presumably could copy the platform normal button drawable and use that as your background.